# What is a better design for sending and returning data objects from a service layer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am probably thinking about this too much but was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do the following. Please note that my main concern is the use of the Data Transfer Object. This works excellent just seems messy to me.

Example DTO:

```
 public class UserDto:DtoBase
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid NamedIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string ProviderIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public DateTime PasswordExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public int InvalidLoginAttempts { get; set; }
    public int AccountLocked { get; set; }
    public int AccountValidated { get; set; }
    public string AccountKey { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public ProfileDto Profile { get; set; }
}
```

Example Service Method.

```
  public CreateUserResult CreateUser(UserDto userDto)
    {
        ISession session = _sessionManager.OpenSession();
        int accountValidated = 1;

        try
        {
            if (_applicationConfiguration.AccountValidationEnabled)
            {
                accountValidated = 0;
            }

            if (session.QueryOver<User>().Where(x => x.UserName == userDto.UserName).RowCount() > 0)
            {
                return new CreateUserResult
                {
                    CreateUserStatus = CreateUserStatus.UserExists
                };
            }

            string accountKey = _encryption.GenerateMd5HashString(_encryption.GenerateRandomString(8));
            string hash;
            string salt;

            _encryption.GethashAndSaltString(userDto.Password, out hash, out salt);

            IList<Role> roles =
                session.QueryOver<Role>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).Take(10).List<Role>();

            var userEntity = new User
            {
                UserName = userDto.UserName,
                Password = hash,
                Salt = salt,
                PasswordExpires = _applicationConfiguration.PasswordExpirationDays,
                InvalidLoginAttempts = 0,
                AccountLocked = 0,
                AccountValidated = accountValidated,
                AccountKey = accountKey,
                Active = 1,
                LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Profile = new Profile
                {
                    DisplayName = userDto.Profile.DisplayName,
                    EmailAddress = userDto.Profile.EmailAddress,
                    Bio = userDto.Profile.Bio,
                    Active = 1,
                    DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow
                },
            };
            foreach (Role roleEntity in
                userDto.Roles.Where(role => roles.Any(x => x.Name == role))
                    .Select(role => roles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == role))
                    .Where(roleEntity => roleEntity != null))
            {
                userEntity.Roles.Add(roleEntity);
            }

            session.Save(userEntity);

            return new CreateUserResult
            {
                CreateUserStatus = CreateUserStatus.Success,
                User = new UserDto
                {
                    UserId = userEntity.UserId,
                    NamedIdentifier = userEntity.UserId,
                    UserName = userEntity.UserName,
                    Password = userEntity.Password,
                    Salt = userEntity.Salt,
                    PasswordExpirationDate = userEntity.PasswordExpires,
                    InvalidLoginAttempts = userEntity.InvalidLoginAttempts,
                    AccountLocked = userEntity.AccountLocked,
                    AccountValidated = userEntity.AccountValidated,
                    AccountKey = userEntity.AccountKey,
                    Active = userEntity.Active,
                    LastLoginDate = userEntity.LastLoginDate,
                    DateCreated = userEntity.DateCreated,
                    LastUpdated = userEntity.LastLoginDate,
                    Profile = new ProfileDto
                    {
                        ProfileId = userEntity.Profile.ProfileId,
                        DisplayName = userEntity.Profile.DisplayName,
                        EmailAddress = userEntity.Profile.EmailAddress,
                        Bio = userEntity.Profile.Bio,
                        Active = userEntity.Profile.Active,
                        DateCreated = userEntity.Profile.DateCreated,
                        LastUpdated = userEntity.Profile.LastUpdated
                    },
                    Roles = userEntity.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
                }
            };
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Error(exception.Message);

            return new CreateUserResult
            {
                CreateUserStatus = CreateUserStatus.Failed
            };
        }
    }
```

Controller ActionResult:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignUp(UsersSignUpViewModel usersSignUpViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(usersSignUpViewModel);
        }
        string userName = usersSignUpViewModel.UserName;
        string password = usersSignUpViewModel.Password;
        string displayName = usersSignUpViewModel.DisplayName;
        string returnUrl = usersSignUpViewModel.ReturnUrl;

        if (!Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            returnUrl = "/";
        }

        var user = new UserDto
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Password = password,
            Roles = new[] {_applicationConfiguration.DefaultRole, "Admin"},
            Profile = new ProfileDto
            {
                DisplayName = displayName,
                EmailAddress = userName
            }
        };
        CreateUserResult createUserResult = _userService.CreateUser(user);

        switch (createUserResult.CreateUserStatus)
        {
            case CreateUserStatus.Success:
                UserDto userResult = createUserResult.User;
                ClaimsIdentity identity = _identityManager.GetIdentity(createUserResult.User);
                _owinContext.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = false
                }, identity);

                return Json(new {authenticated=true,returnUrl=returnUrl});

            case CreateUserStatus.Failed:
                break;
            case CreateUserStatus.UserExists:
                ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Unable to create account");
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        return PartialView("_SignUp", usersSignUpViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: So, what part do you feel is messy?

Comment: The use of the DTO Just seems like a bunch of code to me

Comment: What would you use instead of a DTO? BTW, DTO is a common design pattern.

Comment: I am passing in an instance of the DTO and my method returns the DTO wrapped up with the Status.. Not all of the properties are set when being passed in to the method but they are when I returrn it

Comment: Of course you should only return the properties required. If you wind up with several objects which only differ in a few properties, then that's ok. But don't include properties in the DTO that are not used in a particular situation.

Comment: Excellent, I will create a new DTO to pass in since it only reqquires a few properties and leave the other one intact

Comment: Thanks Post that as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you should only return the properties required. If you wind up with several objects which only differ in a few properties, then that's ok. But don't include properties in the DTO that are not used in a particular situation.

Comment: That seems much cleaner, I was paranoid about having too many classes but it makes sense. I am fairly new to all of this and trying to do things the correct way.